# When to use Interface and when to use Abstract class

Tags: java, user-interface, polymorphism, abstract-class

Folks can you explain me in which condition I should go with Interface and at which condition should I prefer Abstract class ... ? keep in mind I am not asking difference between Interface and Abstract class.

Comment: Refer this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12993123/confused-about-java-interface/12995321#12995321

Comment: I want to say something like: "Favour collaboration over inheritance" which could almost be interpreted to mean that Abstract Classes are never needed....

Comment: Abstract classes are useful in a lot of situations... you have to learn which situation each best answer the problems to solve.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

We must preferred first to inferface. If we have to write some common functionality in that class then and only then you can go for abstract class. Otherwise use interface. Because We can implement number of interface but we can extend only one class so for future you must go for interface rather than abstract class.

Comment: There's other use of inheritance than sharing common code.

Comment: Please explain me so I will get more clarification

Comment: [Read this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/479142/when-to-use-an-interface-instead-of-an-abstract-class-and-vice-versa) and the other linked...

Answer (score 1):

If you found any Is a relationships between objects you can use `abstract`
for example: `Bird, Aeroplane, Paper Rocket` these all are flyable but there is no any `Is a relationship` between these objects, so you can use here `interface` instead of `abstract`,
Because Bird,Aeroplane and Paper Rocket all are flyable but the way of flying is different.

And off course lots of differences are on Google.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Abstract class` when : You have some common functionality (method) which must be implemented at only one place and other concrete classes can just use it.

Use `Interface` when : There is no common functionality. Every concrete class has its own implementation of functionality.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to stick to the following rules:

- use an abstract class only, if you need `code-reuse`
- restrict the visibility to the package the abstract class is defined

Otherwise use an interface and delegation. But as it is with software design you have to make the proper decision for each concrete situation. If you have restriction / rules which must be applied but need some flexibility, think about using the strategy-pattern in preference to inheritance.

The problem with abstract classes is that you can't inherit from more then one. Hence, if you need a type which `is` of type `A` and `B` and both are abstract classes, how do you achieve this? Interfaces are open to be implemented by any other type without restrictions.